# Cannot persist doctrine entity, foreign keys always null despite setting them

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I just cannot seem to figure out what I've done wrong. I am working with Symfony and I have created an entity called "UserProfile". It has a user_id and an account_id. I set them within a controller like so:

```
$profile = new UserProfile;
$profile->setAccountId($account->getId())
    ->setUserId($user->getId());
```

I then attempt to persist the entity like so:

```
$entityManager->persist($profile);
$entityManager->flush();
```

If I dump the profile, it shows that the account_id is set to 1 and the user_id is set to 17 (which is exactly what I would expect). And yet, when I attempt to persist the entity, I get an exception saying that account_id and user_id cannot be null. Here is my entity definition. I can only assume I have done something wrong with its definition. Please let me know if you need anything else to help me diagnose my problem. Thank you all in advance!

```
<?php

namespace Denizen\AppBundle\Entity;

use DateTime;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * UserProfile
 *
 * I have set up a unique index on account_id/user_id so that only one profile may exist per user per account.
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Denizen\AppBundle\Repository\UserProfileRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="users_profiles", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="account_user_profile_unique", columns={"account_id", "user_id"})})
 */
class UserProfile
{

    const STATUS_NEW = 'new';

    const STATUS_COMPLETED = 'completed';

    /**
     * @var User
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="profiles")
     */
    protected $user;

    /**
     * @var Account
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Account", inversedBy="profiles")
     */
    protected $account;

    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="user_id", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $userId;

    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="account_id", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $accountId;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", name="status", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $status;

    /** snip **/

    /**
     * UserProfile constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->setStatus(static::STATUS_NEW);
    }

    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    public function getAccount()
    {
        return $this->account;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId(): int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getUserId(): int
    {
        return $this->userId;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $userId
     */
    public function setUserId(int $userId)
    {
        $this->userId = $userId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getAccountId(): int
    {
        return $this->accountId;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $accountId
     */
    public function setAccountId(int $accountId)
    {
        $this->accountId = $accountId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getStatus(): ?string
    {
        return $this->status;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $status
     * @return UserProfile
     */
    public function setStatus(?string $status)
    {
        $this->status = $status;
        return $this;
    }

    /** snip **/

}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the "mappedBy" property on the User and Account entities? It could be that doctrine is unaware of the relation between these entities

Comment: Your entity is not set up properly.  You do not want to have `$userId` or `$accountId` there, those are handled by `$user` and `$account` already.

Comment: So does that mean that I don't set `$profile->setAccountId($account->getId())` but rather `$profile->setAccount($account)` ? And if so, then that means I must manually create these methods, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you shouldn't have to define the properties $userId and $accountId since you are already defining a $user and an $account properties, also in the definition you should tell to symfony which is the join column name.
For example if your 'profile' table in your database schema has a 'user_id' column, you should map it as follows:

```
   /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="profiles")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id")
     */
    protected $user;
```

Assuming that the name for column 'user_id' is the same for the table 'profile' and 'user'

Then to create an instance of UserProfile

```
$userProfile = new UserProfile();
$userProfile->setUser($someExistingUser);
$entityManager->persist($userProfile);
$entityManager->flush();
```

Also if you want to retrieve the user id later you should do it as follows

```
$userId = $userProfile->getUser()->getId();
```

depending of the names for the getter and setter methods in your entity

Comment: Thanks everybody you have been very helpful. You have solved my problem(s).